# How to schedule an at job to take place in the past?

Tags: linux, at

I have an interesting situation where it would be useful to schedule an `at` job in the past, to be triggered after a reboot on a system that doesn't maintain a real-time clock during power-down.

If I attempt to do this, `at` rejects the command (since it is in the past).

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you use the `@reboot` in the crontab? We have a script that enables/disables the `@reboot` for a couple of things.

Comment: Do you know there's a utility like "fake hwclock"?